# How to prioritize rows with specific condition when on Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization

I have this table as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."items" (
    "name" text NOT NULL,
    "type" text NOT NULL
)
```

With initial values:

```
INSERT INTO "items" ("name", "type") VALUES
('apple',   'fruit'),
('banana',  'fruit'),
('chair',   'furniture'),
('table',   'furniture'),
('grape',   'fruit'),
('cabbage', 'vegetable'),
('beef',    'meat'),
('water',   'drinks'),
('lamp',    'furniture');
```

How can I query rows from this table with **one statement** so that I get the rows with the `fruit` type first?

Given that:

- There's a lot of `type`s (could be in thousands of different `type`s)
- I don't care the order of the result other than I want to prioritize getting `fruit` type first

For example if I want to query 5 rows from this table, the result would be `'apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'cabbage' and 'beef'`.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you, that solves it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a boolean expression as the first `ORDER BY` expression:

---

```
SELECT * FROM items
ORDER BY (type='fruit') DESC, name
   ;
```